# Accessing User Rating Information from Steam

Tags: php, steam, steam-web-api

My Google-Fu has failed me. I am looking for a way to easily access the user rating system on `Steam`.

What I have is the User's `64bit SteamID`, The user's list of owned games in the form of appids, and access to `Steam-Web-Api`. I could set up a number of CURL requests to harvest the information from the store, but I am hoping that I can just get it through an API somewhere.

Can anyone point me in the right direction for access this information?

Thanks!!

Comment: https://steamcommunity.com/dev/

Comment: I have been through the documentation for the web api and I can't find what I am looking for.

Comment: Have you tried the laravel package? https://packagist.org/packages/syntax/steam-api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think review information is available in the Web API at the moment.

What you could do is get the app's store page, for example, http://store.steampowered.com/app/270880, you have the app IDs from the API, and scrape the review numbers from the HTML. This is not future-safe because they will change the layout at some point, but that's how I would do it.

Comment: That is what I ended up doing. I'm going to have to stay on top of making sure I am scraping the right information as you mention.